# USB storage alert whenever camera used

Tags: sd-card, camera, samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-storage

I use Samsung GT P1000. It displays "turn off USB storage before using camera" each time I try to use the camera. It also doesn't see the memory card. I have a done factory reset several times. What I can do to correct these problems?